# Is there a punctuation mark for the semicomma?

Tags: punctuation

A semi comma is exactly like a question mark, but it has a comma under the question mark instead of a period. It is used in a sentence when the speaker or writer gets half-way through the sentence and forgets what they intended to say. This might happen, for example, when the speaker is high. Use of the punctuation mark permits simply abandoning the sentence half-way through without feeling the need to erase or delete already-written text. It's like I was telling my friend...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Superimpose a comma to a question mark, but I doubt that readers will understand the meaning.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\semicomma}{%
  {\ooalign{?\cr\hidewidth,\hidewidth\cr}}%
}

\begin{document}

``Ops\semicomma''

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=11808945#11808945

Comment: Thanks. That will do. By the way--a little-known fact--the trailing quote is misplaced. This is true in both Amerian and British English (surprisingly) and even in the case of the mark's use in a direct quotation. Weird, but true.

Comment: Apart from the reader not understanding the meaning, such a change is too subtle and the reader will probably interpret it as an artefact of printing.

Comment: I think that `partial phrase\dots ?` is more understandable. In Spanish you could try using `¿ partial phrase\dots` without closing the interrogative phrase, which if read aloud gives the "right" intonation.